# How to avoid multiple JavaScript function calls in Infinite Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, jquery-events

I'm using this JavaScript functions to create a JSP page with Infinite Scroll feature.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

var count = 0;

window.onload = loadSubPage;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    alert("load appLeadershipSubView function calling");
        loadSubPage();
    }
});

function loadSubPage()
{
    alert("load appLeadershipSubView called");
        $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'appLeadershipSubView.do?count=' + count,
        async : true,
        beforeSend: function(){
        },
        success: function(html){
            alert("success event");
            $('#mainDiv').append(html);
            count++;
        },
        complete: function(){
        }
    }
    );
} 

</script>
```

---

As you can see
I'm calling the `loadSubPage` function to append html content in the `appLeadershipSubView` page into the `#mainDiv`.
And `loadSubPage` is also called at the page Load event also.

The Problem is when I scroll down it makes multiple (2 sometimes 3) calls to the `loadSubPage` function and appends duplicate data into the div.

Since I'm new to JSP and Javascript I couldn't figure out the problem here.
Can you please point me out the problem here?

Comment: Another issue came up with this code. (I wasn't sure about posting as a separate question) This function call works absolutely fine with FireFox but it doesn't work in Chrome. It only calls the function once and doesn't call it again. I didn't get any dialog box asking whether to 'stop generating anymore message boxes' Can you guys help me with this too? :)

Comment: You should definitely post this as a new question. Also include the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a Boolean to make sure there is not an active request. Check to see if it is active before you make a request.

```
var isActive = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if  (!isActive && $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    isActive = true;
```

in the callback, set isActive to false

```
success: function(html){
    $('#mainDiv').append(html);
    isActive = false;
```

Comment: ... and reset that boolean in the callback.

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather use [Underscore's throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) function for that!

Much cleaner, non-hackish, and you'll focus on your app's logic rather than doing some callbacks-boolean-reset-magic.

Comment: Why including another library when a single variable does the trick?

Comment: @Amberlamps Because it's cleaner (as in easier to read), because you can screw something in your code while the code from that library is well-tested  and because that library can save you a lot of code.

Comment: Also there is no hackish attribute to it whatsoever. I just had a look into Underscore´s source code, they are using a control variable `throttling` themselves.

Comment: @Amberlamps which is hidden in Underscore's namespace, resulting in less bug-propone code.

Comment: It is just a matter of how you implement your solution.

Comment: Thank You too alexandernst!!! 
"boolean-reset-magic" worked ;) 
Anyway i'll give a try using Underscore's throttle also. :)